# octa.com : How to verify user with push notification challenge?

Tags: authentication, push-notification, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

octa.com provides different APIs to identify user by multi-factor authentication process. One of the way to do it is send push notification on octa mobile app installed on user's mobile device.

I am facing difficulty to send push notification using octa.com APIs. Please share your ideas if anybody has already done this before.

There are 2 main steps as given below:

1. Send push notification to registered user's mobile device.
2. Check if user has taken any actions on sent push notification (example : how Google asks us to verify if we have logged in to some other device or not).

Now there are multiple APIs we need to use to complete above process:

1. Enrollment/ to get factor id
   https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#enroll-okta-verify-push-factor
2. Activate push factor
   https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#activate-push-factor
3. send push notification
   https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#issue-a-push-factor-challenge
4. polling/verify push notification transaction
   https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#response-example-26